# Why is E_OUTOFMEMORY followed by "no more threads can be created"?

Tags: .net, com, windows-server-2008-r2, azure-web-roles

I have effectively this code (it looks insane with all those `try`-`catch`es but I really need them to illustrate the problem):

```
Exception doStuffException = null;
try {
   someComObject.DoStuff();
} catch( Exception e ) {
   doStuffException = e;
   throw;
} finally {
   try {
      someComObject.Cleanup();
   } catch( Exception e ) {
      var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
      foreach( var p in processes ) {
         //log p.Threads.Count and p.ProcessName
      }
      throw;
   }
}
```

The COM object resides in an out-proc server process. Both the client and the COM server run inside Azure web role and I don't know whether the same behavior would reoccur outside Azure.

Most of the time it just works - `DoStuff()` runs okay, then `Cleanup()` runs okay. Sometimes on some specific datasets `DoStuff()` yields `System.OutOfMemoryException` and then `Cleanup()` runs and yields `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` with error code `0x800700A4` which corresponds to `ERROR_MAX_THRDS_REACHED` define in winerror.h and has text "No more threads can be created in the system`. The code that enumerates all processes runs and none of the processes has any unreasonable treads count and the process hosting the COM server has thread count equal to 3 (yes, just three).

Once `ERROR_MAX_THRDS_REACHED` happens all the calls to that COM server also yield `ERROR_MAX_THRDS_REACHED` until the COM server is restarted.

What could cause `ERROR_MAX_THRDS_REACHED` when there's no obvious leakage of threads?

Comment: And this behavior only happens in Azure ? If not, I would strip the Azure tag. Also it is good to mention what type of service you are using. Azure VM or Azure Cloud Service. Guessing a Cloud Service (Worker Role) but you never mention it.

Comment: @astaykov: I don't know if this is reproducible outside Azure. I edited the question.

Comment: @sharptooth, when you call out `someComObject.DoStuff()`, does it result in any events sourced from the COM object and handled by .NET?

Comment: @Noseratio: No, there're no events going back.

Comment: Could you check the thread counts before and after  `someComObject.DoStuff()` (i.e., before calling `someComObject.Cleanup()`)?

Comment: @Noseratio: No, I haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much observation it's clear that in most cases the issue is reproduced the COM server process will have almost all memory consumed (the COM server is a 32-bit process so it can't consume more that 2 gigabytes of memory).

This likely happens because of memory fragmentation or memory leak - hard to say without further analysis. This in turn likely leads to not enough memory to create a new thread (which is needed to serve the COM client request) and the latter is likely being diagnosed as "no more threads can be created" instead of "not enough memory" in the COM server (that error code is returned to the client and observed by the client).

I have no proof that it works exactly this way but this is the best explanation I can come up with. It looks like it's just memory shortage preventing new threads creation and being reported as "no more threads can be created".

Comment: Came here because I got the same error locally and the cause seems to have been the same. A 32-bit COM server (DVBViewer in my case) had managed to hit >3.5GB memory and the COM interface was reporting "No more threads can be created in the system". No processes were actually using excessive threads.